# People Crawl no longer working, web service redirecting to Login

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, crawling, people-search

Our People Crawl had been working for awhile and recently after installing SP1 in our environments it seems that the People Crawl has been failing.  The accounts still have the proper permissions, our extended site (which search crawls are using) is set to be anonymous with NTLM - we utilize claims on our sites.  The search account can crawl through the site with no problems when using a browser but when the SharePoint crawl service is started we get one error:

> The SharePoint server was moved to a different location. (
>   HttpStatusCode Found The request failed with the error message: --
>   Object moved
>
> ### Object moved
>   to here.
>
> --. )

Checking various settings we have the right permissions, there is no HTTPS redirect on the extended site (our general site has HTTPS set for the login pages) and sps3 worked fine until just before SP1.  I am not sure it's SP1 that has caused the problem, it's probably not, but something occurred just around the same time to cause this.

Any troubleshooting ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SP1 our current site was no longer alloweding the People Crawl access through the sps3 protocol, for some reason this only works on the extended site.  Our extended site is set up with anonymous access, more for the Search Content Crawl to work, this is on port 81 so placing the port number on the content source as sps3://hostname:81 allows the People Crawl to now successfully run.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the same problem, but this solution did not help. After I had realized that my MSH was running on https (and not http) I changed protocol an Content Source from SPS3 to SPS3S and crawler started working as expected